# Язык по умолчанию Polylang

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, polylang

Как на WordPress, с мультиязычным плагином Polylang сделать язык по умолчанию, чтобы загружал в приоритете только его? 
То есть сейчас это работает так, что он определяет язык браузера и отображает соотв. язык. Нужно чтобы вне зависимости от этого, он показывал язык по умолчанию.

Comment: В документации это почти в самом начале, нужно только ее почитать чуть чуть

Comment: Действительно, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Languages -> Setings -> Detect browser language (сделать Deactivate)

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно зайти в настройки плагина и отключить соответствующий модуль.